# Ndk-build not permitted to link to gnu stl

Tags: android, boost, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I'm working on an Android project using the NDK and a Boost library and libraries that are part of the Cocos2d-x game engine. I think the problem I'm having is a simple problem linking libraries and using NDK, but I mention Boost and cocos2d-x for completeness.

When I go to build my project using ndk-build, all of my code appears to be compiled to object files fine, suggesting that g++ can locate all of the library headers I'm using. G++ explodes when the linking starts, I believe, as it tries to build the shared library tying my code and libraries together.

The build log, with errors, can be found here: http://txtup.co/tMtJ

The first error to come up,

C:/Android/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: error: cannot open ./obj/local/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a: Permission denied

Seems highly telling, since libgnustl_static.a ought to contain implementations for all the functions like 'std::string::operator+' that g++ says it can't find reference to after that error.

libgnustl_static.a is copied into the ./obj/local/armeabi during the build, so I know that my makefiles are at least aware of the library at some point. I would guess that happens prior to that 'permission denied' error, but I can't be sure.

Below is my android.mk for the libgame.so library that I want to be the final product of all this compilation:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/libs/armeabi

LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += hellocpp/main.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes \
            $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libboost_serialization/include/ \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libboost_serialization/include/boost/archive \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt/libboost_serialization/include/boost/serialization                

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := boost_1_53_serialization cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static cocos_extension_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,libboost_serialization) \
$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) \
$(call import-module,cocos2dx) \
$(call import-module,extensions)
```

Is there some reason that makefile wouldn't be able to find or use libgnustl_static? Or is there something to how the library is copied into the working directory that changes permissions?

Comment: If you check after the error, is the file readable?   Is it actually an ndk compatible library?

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I'm not sure I understand your questions. The rest of the error file is readable... although it appears to get cut a bit short by that text uploader. There is no interesting output missing, though, just more undefined references to std classes and functions.

All of the libraries I'm using ought to be ndk compatible. They were either included with the NDK when I downloaded it (as with libgnustl_static), or were successfully compiled against that version of the ndk (cocos2d, libboost_serialization).

Comment: Is the .a file readable after the build fails?

Comment: Oh, I see. No, libgame.so isn't generated at all, that I can see.

Comment: The .a file it claims it can't read.  Can you, from the same commandline?

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for clarifying again. I do get 'permission denied' when I try to open or view the contents of ./obj/local/armeabi/libgnustl_static.a

Comment: So my problem is still, how do I allow ndk-build access to that? As far as I know, I don't specify permissions of that file, nor how the library is copied to working directory. I've tried changing permissions of the directory, but rebuilding seems to override the setting.

Comment: Instead of `LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.7/libs/armeabi` put the following line to `Application.mk` (note: NOT Android.mk): `APP_STL := gnustl_static`

Answer (score 0):

We have samples in cocos2d-x using gnustl.

Try basing your *.mk files (both Android.mk and Application.mk) on them:
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/tree/master/samples/Cpp/HelloCpp/proj.android/jni

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `gcc/NDK` that manifests itself slightly differently on Linux, Cygwin, and Windows (non Cygwin).

If you'll run `ndk-build V=1` and pipe that to a log file (e.g. `ndk-build V=1 &> logfile`). You'll see a bunch of your objects being compiled and down a little further you'll see them being linked, followed by an "explosion" of link errors- those errors will be related to libgnustl.  Now look at the command that gave rise to the errors.  Prior to NDK r8d the libgnustl_static was copied out of `$(NDK_ROOT)` to your objs directory and linked from there, now you should see that it *is* there but it has to be at (or near) the end for gcc reasons I won't bore you with.

Here's what I did to fix it...

- Remove the line that says, "`APP_STL := gnustl_static`" from your **Application.mk** (it's broken in the NDK, and it's broken slightly differently on Linux Cygwin, Windows)
- add a line to `$(LOCAL_LDLIBS)` in your **Android.mk** file that says, "

  $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a

  "
- also add two lines to **Android.mk** that say,

  LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include
     LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/include

The forgoing will accomplish what having, "`APP_STL := gnustl_static`" in your **Application.mk** was supposed to.